# Pycharm automatic upload deletes file

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-server

I created a remote server configuration for my project on Pycharm. However Pycharm seems to periodically wipe my file contents, and sometimes converts the characters in the file into unreadable ones when I ask it to upload my changes to the folder set up on the server. Undoing changes seems to change it back to the original state, with a popup asking if I should 'undo reload from disk'. The deletion happens immediately after I first try to change the file after I upload to server. To clarify, I am using the Pycharm 2018.2 Professional edition installed on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Here's a screenshot of what I see when I undo the operation that deletes the contents of my file.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxMuZ.png)

I also took a screenshot of the time when it converts it into unreadable characters - 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPoK7.png)

Comment: please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your behavior and conclude what's wrong and why

Comment: I included a more thorough explanation, along with screenshot images.